# Como baixar vários arquivos usando wget?

Tags: php, wget

Galera, preciso baixar todas as imagens de uma pasta num servidor!

Ou seja, existe um site `www.tarararara.com/images`

E lá tem 50 imagens! Como faço para baixar essas imagens e colocá-las em uma pasta do meu servidor usando o comando `wget`?

E preciso baixar todas as imagens do site, para colocar na pasta `images` do Localhost!

Alguma maneira de criar um loop? Ou algo do tipo?

Comment: tem acesso ao ftp ou é um site terceiro?

Comment: site terceiro,,

Comment: Para site terceiro não há o que fazer, a menos que as imagens tenham algum padrão. O negócio aí é usar coisas como wget, file_get_contents(), fopen, curl, etc....

Comment: então, eles tem meio que um padrão para os nomes, mas como disse, não dá pra usar wget, uso Vertrigo no Windows!! e o file_get_contents da pra colocar em uma pasta?

Comment: Afinal, quer fazer fazer isso no php, certo?  Pode usar qualquer uma dessas funções php que fazem streaming e leitura de urls. Quanto a “wget” é um recurso para linux mas tem equivalente nativo no windows ou mesmo pode ter um wget no win32/64.  Joga no google “windows wget”.

Comment: quero fazer apenas um script rápido para baixar as imagens na pasta e pronto, excluo ele dps, sacaram? e digamos que eu ache um wget pra windows, qual seria o comando pra pegar tudo do servidor?

Comment: mesmo com wget dá na mesma.. ainda terá que requisitar um por um num loop.. Tentou fazer algo no php? Poste na pergunta o que tentou fazer até o momento

Comment: Nada, porque sei que algumas coisas são meio que impossíveis nesse Windows!

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com windows.. Defina o que precisa. Quer fazer com wget ou com php?  Por enquanto não está claro qual ferramenta ou ambiente deseja usar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46839/discussion-between-sampaio-leal-and-daniel-omine).

Comment: No começo foi em PHP, já que uso windows! Mas aí me recomendaram o instalar um bagulhu pra meio que simular um terminal Linux! Ai pensei agora que posso usar wget, mas mesmo assim deu erro, tiver que baixar todas as imagens, na raça mesmo! Mas agora eu já sei como fazer com wget! Pergunta resolvida!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wget -nd -r -P /onde.vc.quer.salvar -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://odominio/imagem
```

- O `-np` impede que seja usado recursividade em direção ao diretório
  pai, se não for colocado isso ele tentará fazer *download* de todas as
  imagens que estejam no site.
- O `-r` permite recursividade para os diretório filhos.
- O `-P` vai criar um diretório onde será colocado todas as imagens.
- O `-A` indica todo tipo de arquivo que tu queres.

As possibilidade são grandes e o manual explica muito bem tudo que ele pode fazer:

> https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html

Comment: cara, eu estou usando o sed, n sei se conhece, mas ele n funciona muito bem o wget, fiz a pior coisa da minha vida

Comment: eu abri 100000 abas de todas as imagens

Comment: e arrastei todas para minha pasta, eram umas 80 imagens kk

Comment: mas na próxima já sei como fazer

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe para fazer isso com o  [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) o [Marcos Célio já respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159032/6454), como a pergunta está marcada com a tag [php](/questions/tagged/php), a resposta baseia-se nessa linguagem, você pode tentar o seguinte:

1. Baixar o conteúdo da página com [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) ou [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php), ou outra forma que você conhecer.
2. Extrair os *links* da página, você pode usar a função [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php) ou analisar o HTML com [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php).
3. Baixar o arquivo a partir de uma URL, você pode usar o [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php) ou [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) em conjunto com a função [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php) para abrir o arquivo para escrita.

---

Faça o seguinte:

1. Para baixar o conteúdo da página, com [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php):

   ```
   function obterPagina($url) {
       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

       return curl_exec($curl);
   }
   ```

   <sub>**Nota**: Você pode incluir mais opções dependendo da necessidade. [**Mais informações**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php).</sub>
2. Para extrair os *links* da página, com [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php):

   ```
   function obterLinks($url, $pagina, $extensoes = ['gif', 'jpg']) { // Extensões aceitas
       $dom = new DOMDocument;
       $links = [];

       if ($dom->loadHTML($pagina) !== false) {
           foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) { // Percorre todos os elementos com a tag "a"
               $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
               $extensao = pathinfo($href, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

               if (in_array($extensao, $extensoes)) {
                   $links[] = $url . $href;
               }
           }
           return $links;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```
3. Para baixar o arquivo, também com [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php):

   ```
   function baixarArquivo($url, $salvarComo, $timeout = 3600) {
       $curl = curl_init(); 
       $fp = fopen($salvarComo, 'w'); // Abre o arquivo para escrita

       if (!$fp)
           return false;

       $opts = array(CURLOPT_URL     => $url,
                     CURLOPT_FILE    => $fp,
                     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => $timeout); // Define o timeout, o padrão é 1 hora

       curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);

       $ret = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
       fclose($fp);

       return $ret !== false;
   }
   ```

Para usar, faça assim:

```
$url = "http://www.tarararara.com/images/";
$pagina = obterPagina($url);

if ($pagina) {
    $links  = obterLinks($url, $pagina);

    if ($links) {
        foreach ($links as $link) {
            var_dump( baixarArquivo($link, basename($link)) ); // Salva na mesma pasta do script
        }
    }
}
```